# How C knows size of memory it need to free?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I have pointer to buffer that was initialised with calloc:

```
notEncryptBuf = (unsigned char*) calloc(1024, notEncryptBuf_len);
```

Later I moved pointer to another position:

```
notEncryptBuf+=20;
```

And finally I free buffer:

```
free(notEncryptBuf);
```

Will if free whole allocated size? How C knows size of memory it need to free?

Comment: Did you give it a try? That's one of the cases you're essentially guaranteed a crash.

Comment: There are two unrelated questions in there. One in the title, one in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to answer these kinds of questions is to ask yourself, “how would *I myself* write `malloc()` and `free()`?”

Suppose you have a “memory pool” — fancy words for just an array of bytes:

```
unsigned char memory[10000];
```

Now the user wants eight bytes of that. The user calls `ptr = my_malloc(8)`. You know full well that you can’t just give the user any random spot in your memory array — you can only give away stuff that hasn’t already been given away.

In other words, you somehow need to keep track of what pieces of memory have been given away.

### Linked-lists → Variable-sized elements in an array

One way we know of to manage dynamic memory is through linked-lists. A linked list is a block of memory that you organize with a struct:

```
struct node
{
  SOME_TYPE     data;  // the data to store
  struct node * next;  // a pointer to the next node
};
```

However, since *we* are the memory manager, we don’t have some magic pool to allocate our node. We have to use our own `memory[]` to create space for the node.

Let’s make a simple modification. Instead of a pointer, we will keep track of *how big* a piece is. We can do this with a structure:

```
struct piece_of_memory
{
  int size;
  unsigned char memory[size];
};
```

Memory, then, is just an array of those things, where all the sizes add up to our available memory pool size:

```
piece_of_memory memory[...];
```

So now our initial pool of memory looks like this:

```
int size = 9992;   // 10000 - sizeof(int), which is minus eight bytes on 64-bit systems
unsigned char memory[9992];
```

Graphically, that’s something like

```
[----,------------------------------------------------------------]
 ↑    ↑
9992  memory
```

If I give away eight bytes, that gets reordered:

```
[----,---][----,--------------------------------------------------]
 ↑    ↑    ↑    ↑
 ↑    ↑    ↑    memory
 ↑    ↑    new size = 9992 - 8 - sizeof(int) = 9976
 ↑    ↑
 8    returned from malloc
```

That is two of those `struct`s in a row

```
int size = 8
unsigned char memory[8]
int size = 9976
unsigned char memory[9976]
```

We can verify that the pieces all use exactly 10000 bytes:

```
{(size) 8 + (8 bytes) 8}  +  {(size) 8 + (9976 bytes) 9976}
= 16 + 9984
= 10000
```

So when the user asks us to `ptr = my_malloc(8)`, we find a piece of memory with at least eight available bytes, rearrange things, then return a pointer to the ‘memory’ part (not the ‘size’!).

### Freeing allocated memory

Suppose our user is now finished with the eight bytes and calls `my_free(ptr)`.

```
[----,---][----,--------------------------------------------------]
 8    ↑    9976
      ↑
      free me!
```

We can find our `struct piece_of_memory` (it is `sizeof(int)` bytes before the address returned to us), and we can recombine the free pieces of memory into a whole free block:

```
[----,------------------------------------------------------------]
 9992
```

Notice how this only works if the user gives us an address we gave it earlier, right? What would happen if I returned a wrong `ptr` value?

### More to think about

Naturally we must *also* be able to keep track of which blocks are available to return and which ones are in use. This makes our `struct piece_of_memory` a bit more complicated. We could do something like:

```
struct piece_of_memory
{
  int size;
  bool is_used;
  unsigned char memory[];
};
```

We also need a way for the memory manager to search through the memory blocks for a piece that is big enough for the requested size. If we want to be smart about it, we might take some time to find the *smallest* available block that is big enough for the requested size.

We don’t actually have to keep the (‘size’ and ‘is_used’) with the ‘memory’ pieces, either. We *could* split up our struct to simply have an array of (‘size’ + ‘is_used’) structures at one end of our `memory[]` array and all the pieces of returned memory at the other end.

Finally, we must *waste* a little memory when we divide it up in order to make sure that we always return a pointer that is aligned for the worst-case alignment needs our user might put it to. For example, if user wants to get dynamic memory for an array of `double`, we don’t want to return something that is byte-aligned.

#### This isn’t the only way to do it!

This is just *one* simple way. More advanced structures could certainly be used as well.

### Conclusions

Hopefully you can answer your own questions now:

- How does the memory manager know how much memory to free?
  (Because it keeps track of it.)
- Can I return a pointer that was not given to me by the memory manager?
  (No, because it would break things.)

Obviously the memory manager can be written to prevent things from breaking if you try to free a pointer it did not give you, but the C specification does not require it to. It requires (expects) the user to not give it bad input.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of `free` is specified only if it is passed an address that was previously returned by `malloc` or a related routine or is passed a null pointer (in which case it does nothing). If you pass an address modified from an original allocation, as by `notEncryptBuf += 20;`, the behavior of `free` is not specified.

C implementations commonly know how much space is in an allocation because they store it in some bytes immediately preceding the allocation. For example, if you ask for 1,024 byes, it may allocate 1,040, record information about the allocation in the first 16 bytes, and return to you the address 16 bytes after the whole allocation. Then, when you pass that address to `free`, it looks in the 16 bytes before that address to see the amount of space.

Other implementations are theoretically possible. For example, a memory manager could designate one zone of memory for common fixed-size allocations, such as 32 bytes, and then use a bitmap to indicate whether each 32-byte block in that zone is free or allocated. Or it could keep a database of allocations, using a hash table or trees or other data structures. When `free` is called, it would look up the address in the database.

Answer (score 3):

> *How C knows size of memory it need to free?*

"C" does not know about memory allocation or freeing. It relies on the underlying memory manager to keep track of the allocated memories and free them up.

That said, if you pass a pointer to `free()` which was not returned by any allocator function, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, you cannot pass the pointer which you have *shifted* to `free()`. You need to pass the pointer which was returned by `calloc()`.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are part of C, and compilers may and do know about memory allocation and freeing and may and do optimize some uses of them rather than relying on the underlying memory manager.